# How can I write this function without using an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

This is an exercise from a course. Given an array of objects I had to use the map method to cycle all the elements and return in a new variable, called "rating", a new array containing just the Title and Rating property for each object. The given array of obejcts is this one:

```
var watchList = [
             {  
               "Title": "Inception",
               "Year": "2010",
               "Rated": "PG-13",
               "Released": "16 Jul 2010",
               "Runtime": "148 min",
               "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Crime",
               "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
               "Writer": "Christopher Nolan",
               "Actors": "Leonardo DiCaprio, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Ellen Page, Tom Hardy",
               "Plot": "A thief, who steals corporate secrets through use of dream-sharing technology, is given the inverse task of planting an idea into the mind of a CEO.",
               "Language": "English, Japanese, French",
               "Country": "USA, UK",
               "Awards": "Won 4 Oscars. Another 143 wins & 198 nominations.",
               "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjAxMzY3NjcxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTI5OTM0Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
               "Metascore": "74",
               "imdbRating": "8.8",
               "imdbVotes": "1,446,708",
               "imdbID": "tt1375666",
               "Type": "movie",
               "Response": "True"
            },
            {  
               "Title": "Interstellar",
               "Year": "2014",
               "Rated": "PG-13",
               "Released": "07 Nov 2014",
               "Runtime": "169 min",
               "Genre": "Adventure, Drama, Sci-Fi",
               "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
               "Writer": "Jonathan Nolan, Christopher Nolan",
               "Actors": "Ellen Burstyn, Matthew McConaughey, Mackenzie Foy, John Lithgow",
               "Plot": "A team of explorers travel through a wormhole in space in an attempt to ensure humanity's survival.",
               "Language": "English",
               "Country": "USA, UK",
               "Awards": "Won 1 Oscar. Another 39 wins & 132 nominations.",
               "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxNTU4MzY4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzM4ODI3MjE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
               "Metascore": "74",
               "imdbRating": "8.6",
               "imdbVotes": "910,366",
               "imdbID": "tt0816692",
               "Type": "movie",
               "Response": "True"
            },
            {
               "Title": "The Dark Knight",
               "Year": "2008",
               "Rated": "PG-13",
               "Released": "18 Jul 2008",
               "Runtime": "152 min",
               "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Crime",
               "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
               "Writer": "Jonathan Nolan (screenplay), Christopher Nolan (screenplay), Christopher Nolan (story), David S. Goyer (story), Bob Kane (characters)",
               "Actors": "Christian Bale, Heath Ledger, Aaron Eckhart, Michael Caine",
               "Plot": "When the menace known as the Joker wreaks havoc and chaos on the people of Gotham, the caped crusader must come to terms with one of the greatest psychological tests of his ability to fight injustice.",
               "Language": "English, Mandarin",
               "Country": "USA, UK",
               "Awards": "Won 2 Oscars. Another 146 wins & 142 nominations.",
               "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTMxNTMwODM0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODAyMTk2Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
               "Metascore": "82",
               "imdbRating": "9.0",
               "imdbVotes": "1,652,832",
               "imdbID": "tt0468569",
               "Type": "movie",
               "Response": "True"
            },
            {  
               "Title": "Batman Begins",
               "Year": "2005",
               "Rated": "PG-13",
               "Released": "15 Jun 2005",
               "Runtime": "140 min",
               "Genre": "Action, Adventure",
               "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
               "Writer": "Bob Kane (characters), David S. Goyer (story), Christopher Nolan (screenplay), David S. Goyer (screenplay)",
               "Actors": "Christian Bale, Michael Caine, Liam Neeson, Katie Holmes",
               "Plot": "After training with his mentor, Batman begins his fight to free crime-ridden Gotham City from the corruption that Scarecrow and the League of Shadows have cast upon it.",
               "Language": "English, Urdu, Mandarin",
               "Country": "USA, UK",
               "Awards": "Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 15 wins & 66 nominations.",
               "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNTM3OTc0MzM2OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNzUwMTI3._V1_SX300.jpg",
               "Metascore": "70",
               "imdbRating": "8.3",
               "imdbVotes": "972,584",
               "imdbID": "tt0372784",
               "Type": "movie",
               "Response": "True"
            },
            {
               "Title": "Avatar",
               "Year": "2009",
               "Rated": "PG-13",
               "Released": "18 Dec 2009",
               "Runtime": "162 min",
               "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Fantasy",
               "Director": "James Cameron",
               "Writer": "James Cameron",
               "Actors": "Sam Worthington, Zoe Saldana, Sigourney Weaver, Stephen Lang",
               "Plot": "A paraplegic marine dispatched to the moon Pandora on a unique mission becomes torn between following his orders and protecting the world he feels is his home.",
               "Language": "English, Spanish",
               "Country": "USA, UK",
               "Awards": "Won 3 Oscars. Another 80 wins & 121 nominations.",
               "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwOTEwNjAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODc5MTUwMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
               "Metascore": "83",
               "imdbRating": "7.9",
               "imdbVotes": "876,575",
               "imdbID": "tt0499549",
               "Type": "movie",
               "Response": "True"
            }];
```

The final result should be as follow:

```
[{"title":"Inception","rating":"8.8"},{"title":"Interstellar","rating":"8.6"},{"title":"The Dark Knight","rating":"9.0"},{"title":"Batman Begins","rating":"8.3"},{"title":"Avatar","rating":"7.9"}]
```

Honestly as I couldn't really come up with the solution, I looked for it and found this one:

```
rating = watchList.map( (item) => ({"title":item["Title"], "rating":item["imdbRating"]}) );
```

However this is an arrow function which I only partially understand, so I was trying to solve it using ECMA5 rules and i tried this:

```
var rating = watchList.map(function (item){
let obj ={
   "title":item["Title"], 
    "rating":item["imdbRating"]
    }
    return obj;
```

});

My point was, for every element the map function cycles it returns an object in the new array but showing on console the result was:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

So, how can I write the function without using an arrow function and obtain the exact result?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your function looks fine. What happens when you "open" one of the result objects in the array via the debug console?

Comment: I agree with Pointy. Since you are only using the function parameter, no reference to `this` or to other bindings, using arrow notation or 'plain old' `function` is equivalent here. The only issue you have is a display issue.

Comment: I wrote it in the last part. It gives me and array of [object Object]... but it doesn't show the values

Comment: What browser are you using? Firefox and Chrome show interactive results in the console. You can click on the little triangles to the left of the array and see each object value individually. The console is a tool that's designed to be useful; it does not just dump out a raw static rendering of complex data structures.

Comment: you probably just need to output some JSON version . try `JSON.stringify(yourResult)`. Also, if you do a `console.log(yourResult)`, you hsould be able to click on the "object object" and see the actual objects, if there is no other mistake. (it shouldn't be the *string* "object object"). If you do that from a node.js console instead, or other, try use `console.log(JSON.stringify(yourResult))`

Comment: I agree with all the people said that there is nothing wrong in your piece of code. I just copied and paste your code in the fiddle. Just check it: https://jsfiddle.net/5k2gbadx/

Comment: I'm on Firefox, but the console used is the one provided by the online course. So basically if it doesn't work in their console I can't pass the test. JSON.stringify doesn't work. Their console should work properly.

Comment: Why dont you log the rating items one by one?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! It was a problem with the console. Now it's working fine and it's even showing the result properly using the JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be with the way you are using `console.log`(String concatenation with object prints `[object Object]`).

Both `map` functions generate the same response. Demo here

[image: Edit 9j8mwo2z6p]

Answer (score 1):

It works perfectly - see how I modified the arrow function to an ES5-compliant function:

```js
var watchList = [{
    "Title": "Inception",
    "Year": "2010",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "16 Jul 2010",
    "Runtime": "148 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Crime",
    "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
    "Writer": "Christopher Nolan",
    "Actors": "Leonardo DiCaprio, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Ellen Page, Tom Hardy",
    "Plot": "A thief, who steals corporate secrets through use of dream-sharing technology, is given the inverse task of planting an idea into the mind of a CEO.",
    "Language": "English, Japanese, French",
    "Country": "USA, UK",
    "Awards": "Won 4 Oscars. Another 143 wins & 198 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjAxMzY3NjcxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTI5OTM0Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "74",
    "imdbRating": "8.8",
    "imdbVotes": "1,446,708",
    "imdbID": "tt1375666",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Interstellar",
    "Year": "2014",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "07 Nov 2014",
    "Runtime": "169 min",
    "Genre": "Adventure, Drama, Sci-Fi",
    "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
    "Writer": "Jonathan Nolan, Christopher Nolan",
    "Actors": "Ellen Burstyn, Matthew McConaughey, Mackenzie Foy, John Lithgow",
    "Plot": "A team of explorers travel through a wormhole in space in an attempt to ensure humanity's survival.",
    "Language": "English",
    "Country": "USA, UK",
    "Awards": "Won 1 Oscar. Another 39 wins & 132 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxNTU4MzY4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzM4ODI3MjE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "74",
    "imdbRating": "8.6",
    "imdbVotes": "910,366",
    "imdbID": "tt0816692",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True"
  },
  {
    "Title": "The Dark Knight",
    "Year": "2008",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "18 Jul 2008",
    "Runtime": "152 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Crime",
    "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
    "Writer": "Jonathan Nolan (screenplay), Christopher Nolan (screenplay), Christopher Nolan (story), David S. Goyer (story), Bob Kane (characters)",
    "Actors": "Christian Bale, Heath Ledger, Aaron Eckhart, Michael Caine",
    "Plot": "When the menace known as the Joker wreaks havoc and chaos on the people of Gotham, the caped crusader must come to terms with one of the greatest psychological tests of his ability to fight injustice.",
    "Language": "English, Mandarin",
    "Country": "USA, UK",
    "Awards": "Won 2 Oscars. Another 146 wins & 142 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTMxNTMwODM0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODAyMTk2Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "82",
    "imdbRating": "9.0",
    "imdbVotes": "1,652,832",
    "imdbID": "tt0468569",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Batman Begins",
    "Year": "2005",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "15 Jun 2005",
    "Runtime": "140 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure",
    "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
    "Writer": "Bob Kane (characters), David S. Goyer (story), Christopher Nolan (screenplay), David S. Goyer (screenplay)",
    "Actors": "Christian Bale, Michael Caine, Liam Neeson, Katie Holmes",
    "Plot": "After training with his mentor, Batman begins his fight to free crime-ridden Gotham City from the corruption that Scarecrow and the League of Shadows have cast upon it.",
    "Language": "English, Urdu, Mandarin",
    "Country": "USA, UK",
    "Awards": "Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 15 wins & 66 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNTM3OTc0MzM2OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNzUwMTI3._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "70",
    "imdbRating": "8.3",
    "imdbVotes": "972,584",
    "imdbID": "tt0372784",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Avatar",
    "Year": "2009",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "18 Dec 2009",
    "Runtime": "162 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Fantasy",
    "Director": "James Cameron",
    "Writer": "James Cameron",
    "Actors": "Sam Worthington, Zoe Saldana, Sigourney Weaver, Stephen Lang",
    "Plot": "A paraplegic marine dispatched to the moon Pandora on a unique mission becomes torn between following his orders and protecting the world he feels is his home.",
    "Language": "English, Spanish",
    "Country": "USA, UK",
    "Awards": "Won 3 Oscars. Another 80 wins & 121 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwOTEwNjAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODc5MTUwMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "83",
    "imdbRating": "7.9",
    "imdbVotes": "876,575",
    "imdbID": "tt0499549",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True"
  }
];

var ratings = watchList.map(function(item) {
  return {"Title": item["Title"], "Rating": item["imdbRating"]}
});

console.log(ratings);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, arrow notation or `function` keywords are equivalent for creating a function. This is because you don't use `this` or any external binding. Moreover, your syntax is fine.

Note that if you want to see the actual contents of the object, the "standard" way would be to *get a JSON from your object*.

You should be able to use `console.log(JSON.stringify(yourObject))`, which should give you what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

The console log returns [object,object] for your watchlist because this is an object inside an array, which is correct by the way, I tried your code here by console logging the watch list and it returns the desired array of an object result: https://es6console.com/jr72hz5j/

If you are having a hard time understanding arrow functions I will help you since this is a better implementation than es5 syntax:

```
const rating =  // the Storing of your Variable this should be constant if your don't want the data to be changed and let if you want to change it later
watchList.map( (item) => // this is equal to function(item) {} the item here is each element of your arra.
({"title":item["Title"], // this stores the object with a key of title you can also use item.Title instead
"rating":item["imdbRating"]})  // This stores the imdb rating to your new rating object you can also use item.imdbRating instead for shorter code
);
```

es6 can implement shorter lines and can create shorter implementation. If you have questions just reply in the comments

Answer (score 0):

I compiled your original code to include both ES5 and ES6 functions (both work perfectly), as well as a `console.log('ES5', ratingES5);` and `console.log('ES6', ratingES6);`.

Both console.logs return the desired output. How are you using `console.log`? That is probably the issue.

```
var watchList = [
  {  
   "Title": "Inception",
   "Year": "2010",
   "Rated": "PG-13",
   "Released": "16 Jul 2010",
   "Runtime": "148 min",
   "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Crime",
   "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
   "Writer": "Christopher Nolan",
   "Actors": "Leonardo DiCaprio, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Ellen Page, Tom Hardy",
   "Plot": "A thief, who steals corporate secrets through use of dream-sharing technology, is given the inverse task of planting an idea into the mind of a CEO.",
   "Language": "English, Japanese, French",
   "Country": "USA, UK",
  "Awards": "Won 4 Oscars. Another 143 wins & 198 nominations.",
  "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjAxMzY3NjcxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTI5OTM0Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
  "Metascore": "74",
  "imdbRating": "8.8",
  "imdbVotes": "1,446,708",
  "imdbID": "tt1375666",
  "Type": "movie",
  "Response": "True"
  },
  {  
  "Title": "Interstellar",
  "Year": "2014",
  "Rated": "PG-13",
  "Released": "07 Nov 2014",
  "Runtime": "169 min",
  "Genre": "Adventure, Drama, Sci-Fi",
  "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
  "Writer": "Jonathan Nolan, Christopher Nolan",
  "Actors": "Ellen Burstyn, Matthew McConaughey, Mackenzie Foy, John Lithgow",
  "Plot": "A team of explorers travel through a wormhole in space in an attempt to ensure humanity's survival.",
  "Language": "English",
  "Country": "USA, UK",
  "Awards": "Won 1 Oscar. Another 39 wins & 132 nominations.",
  "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxNTU4MzY4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzM4ODI3MjE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
  "Metascore": "74",
  "imdbRating": "8.6",
  "imdbVotes": "910,366",
  "imdbID": "tt0816692",
  "Type": "movie",
  "Response": "True"
  },
  {
  "Title": "The Dark Knight",
  "Year": "2008",
  "Rated": "PG-13",
  "Released": "18 Jul 2008",
  "Runtime": "152 min",
  "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Crime",
  "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
  "Writer": "Jonathan Nolan (screenplay), Christopher Nolan (screenplay), Christopher Nolan (story), David S. Goyer (story), Bob Kane (characters)",
  "Actors": "Christian Bale, Heath Ledger, Aaron Eckhart, Michael Caine",
  "Plot": "When the menace known as the Joker wreaks havoc and chaos on the people of Gotham, the caped crusader must come to terms with one of the greatest psychological tests of his ability to fight injustice.",
  "Language": "English, Mandarin",
  "Country": "USA, UK",
  "Awards": "Won 2 Oscars. Another 146 wins & 142 nominations.",
  "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTMxNTMwODM0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODAyMTk2Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
  "Metascore": "82",
  "imdbRating": "9.0",
  "imdbVotes": "1,652,832",
  "imdbID": "tt0468569",
  "Type": "movie",
  "Response": "True"
  },
  {  
  "Title": "Batman Begins",
  "Year": "2005",
  "Rated": "PG-13",
  "Released": "15 Jun 2005",
  "Runtime": "140 min",
  "Genre": "Action, Adventure",
  "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
  "Writer": "Bob Kane (characters), David S. Goyer (story), Christopher Nolan (screenplay), David S. Goyer (screenplay)",
  "Actors": "Christian Bale, Michael Caine, Liam Neeson, Katie Holmes",
  "Plot": "After training with his mentor, Batman begins his fight to free crime-ridden Gotham City from the corruption that Scarecrow and the League of Shadows have cast upon it.",
  "Language": "English, Urdu, Mandarin",
  "Country": "USA, UK",
  "Awards": "Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 15 wins & 66 nominations.",
  "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNTM3OTc0MzM2OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNzUwMTI3._V1_SX300.jpg",
  "Metascore": "70",
  "imdbRating": "8.3",
  "imdbVotes": "972,584",
  "imdbID": "tt0372784",
  "Type": "movie",
  "Response": "True"
  },
  {
  "Title": "Avatar",
  "Year": "2009",
  "Rated": "PG-13",
  "Released": "18 Dec 2009",
  "Runtime": "162 min",
  "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Fantasy",
  "Director": "James Cameron",
  "Writer": "James Cameron",
  "Actors": "Sam Worthington, Zoe Saldana, Sigourney Weaver, Stephen Lang",
  "Plot": "A paraplegic marine dispatched to the moon Pandora on a unique mission becomes torn between following his orders and protecting the world he feels is his home.",
  "Language": "English, Spanish",
  "Country": "USA, UK",
  "Awards": "Won 3 Oscars. Another 80 wins & 121 nominations.",
  "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwOTEwNjAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODc5MTUwMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
  "Metascore": "83",
  "imdbRating": "7.9",
  "imdbVotes": "876,575",
  "imdbID": "tt0499549",
  "Type": "movie",
  "Response": "True"
  }
];       

let ratingES6 = watchList.map( (item) => ({"title":item["Title"], "rating":item["imdbRating"]}) );

var ratingES5 = watchList.map(function(item) {
  let obj = { "title":item["Title"], "rating":item["imdbRating"] }
  return obj;
});

console.log('ES5', ratingES5);
// [{"title":"Inception","rating":"8.8"},{"title": "Interstellar","rating":"8.6"},{"title":"The Dark Knight","rating":"9.0"},{"title":"Batman Begins","rating":"8.3"},{"title":"Avatar","rating":"7.9"}]

console.log('ES6', ratingES6);
// logs same output above
```